# Why does mipmapping not work on my 3D texture? (opengl)

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, textures, mipmaps

So I am creating a terrain and for texturing, I want to use a 3D texture (depth 3) which holds 3 images (512x512) on each z-layer, so that I would be able to use GPU interpolation between these layers based on just one factor: 0/3 = image 1, 1/3 = image 2, 2/3 = image 3, and every value in between interpolates with the next level (cyclic).

This works perfectly as long as I don't enable mip maps on this 3D texture. When I do enable it, my terrain gets the same one image all over unless I come closer, as if the images have shifted from being z-layers to being mip-map layers.

I don't understand this, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is where I generate the texture:

```
glGenTextures(1, &m_textureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, m_textureId);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGB, 512, 512, 3, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

This is the step I perform for every Z:

```
glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, Z, 512, 512, 1, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
```

After this, I do:

```
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
```

In the shader, I define the texture as:

```
uniform sampler3D tGround;
```

and simply sample it with:

```
texture(tGround, vec3(texcoord, f));
```

where texcoord is a 2D coordinate and f is the layer we need, simply based on height at this moment.

Comment: Also, can someone explain me why the question is down voted? If I am doing something wrong, please tell me what it is instead of just anonymously down voting it...

Comment: In a 3d texture mipmapping works along ALL axis. So in the level one below the original, there is just one layer left. For me you problem sounds as if you would want to generate mipmaps for each of the three layers separately.

Comment: That makes sense. However, lots of websites say that 3D textures are very useful for what I am trying to do, so it seems there should be a solution. Can this problem be solved somehow?

Comment: Yes. You can supply your own mipmaps instead of using opengls default algorithm. Have a look [here](http://relativity.net.au/gaming/java/TextureMipmap.html).

Comment: @scippie: "*However, lots of websites say that 3D textures are very useful for what I am trying to do, so it seems there should be a solution.*" Which ones? Because if any of them *don't* mention that 3D texture mipmaps also reduce the Z along with the X and Y components, then either they're ignoring mipmapping or they're lying to you.

Comment: @BDL: yes, I know, but if I understand correctly, I will not be able to create more than 1 mip levels for every z, so there will be only a 512x512x3 and a 256x256x1 level, right?

Comment: @NicolBolas: I have seen lots of websites these last days and can't remember, but I must have misinterpreted some stuff. Because now it's obvious to me that I was looking at my 3D texture as an array where it actually wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do something like what you want, but it does require work. And you can't use a 3D texture to do it.

You have to use [Array Textures](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture) instead. The usual way to think of a 2D array texture is as a bundle of 2D textures of the same size. But you can also think of it as a 3D texture where each mipmap level has the same number of Z layers. However, there's also the issue where there is *no blending* between array layers.

Since you want blending, you will need to synthesize it. But that's easy enough with shaders:

```
vec4 ArrayTextureBlend(in vec3 texCoord)
{
  float frac = fract(texCoord.z);
  texCoord.z = floor(texCoord.z);
  vec4 top = texture(arrayTex, texCoord);
  vec4 bottom = texture(arrayTex, texCoord + vec3(0, 0, 1));
  return mix(top, bottom, frac); //Linearly interpolate top and bottom.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was already working on it with Array textures, I have known them for years and meanwhile wrote a similar function. I had just hoped to have a more GPU optimal way, being able to use its natural functionality better. Thanks. As this is imo. the correct answer to the problem, I have marked it as the correct answer.

Comment: BTW: your function is better ;-). Thanks for writing it for me.